# Trying to get F# Closest pair problem working from F# example on www.rosettacode.org/wiki

Tags: f#

```
// F# Brute force: 
let closest_pairs  (xys: Point []) =
  let n = xys.Length  
  seq { for i in 0..n-2 do
          for j in i+1..n-1 do            
          yield xys.[i], xys.[j] }
   |>  Seq.minBy (fun (p0, p1) -> (p1 - p0).LengthSquared)

closest_pairs  [|Point(0.0, 0.0); Point(1.0, 0.0); Point (2.0, 2.0)|]
```

Type constraint mismatch. The type 
    Point
is not compatible with type
    Size
The type 'Point' is not compatible with the type 'Size'

Also Type issues with int v float

F# 2.0, .NET 4, VS 2010

Answer (score 3):

You just need to have defined an appropriate `Point` type first.  Perhaps something like this:

```
type Point(x:float, y) =
  member p.x = x
  member p.y = y
  member p.LengthSquared = x * x + y * y
  static member (-)(p1:Point, p2:Point) = Point(p1.x-p2.x, p1.y-p2.y)
```

Comment: And while you're at it, use Seq.pairwise.

Comment: @Brian - actually, for this problem I think you need to consider any pair of points, not just consecutive pairs.